# The getter 'documentChanges' isn't defined

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This snippet of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots().listen((event){
      event.documentChanges.forEach((change){} //error
}
```

for track the values of users document, But documentChanges attribute has this error:

***The getter 'documentChanges' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documentChanges', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documentChanges'.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.docChanges.forEach((change) {});` instead of `event.documentChanges.forEach((change) {});`

DEPRECATED: `documentChanges` has been deprecated in favor of `docChanges` as of version `0.14.0`. You can view the changelog [here](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog#0140).